# Can't return result from int function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am making a class inherited program in c++. Its function is to determane whenever a triangle is right and to calculate its area.

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Puncte
{
public:
int x1,y1;
int x2,y2;
int x3,y3;
Puncte(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f):x1(a),y1(b),x2(c),y2(d),x3(e),y3(f){}
void AfisareP()
{
cout<<x1<<y1<<x2<<y2<<x3<<y3<<endl;
}
};
class Latura
{
protected:
int l1, l2, l3;
public:
    void LatimeaL(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        l1 = a;
        l2 = b;
        l3 = c;
    }
};
class Triunghi: public Latura
{
public:
    int AriaTrDr()
    {
        return l1*l3/2;
    }
};

int main()
{
Puncte p(2,2,2,2,2,2);
Latura l;
l.LatimeaL(1,2,4);
Triunghi t;
if (p.x1 == p.x3 && p.y1 == p.y2)
{
    cout << "Triunghi dreptunghic!" << endl;
    cout << t.AriaTrDr() << endl;
}

return (0);
}
```

Everthing is working fine but it doesnt show the correct result but the adress and i dont know how to fix it.

This is the result.

```
Triunghi dreptunghic!
513242112
```

Comment: In class `Latura` the `int` members are left with *indeterminate values* after initialization.

Comment: From what I can see, both `Latura l;` and subsequent `l.LatimeaL(1,2,4);` are pointless in `main()`. The should be removed and `t.LatimeaL(1,2,4);` should follow the declaration of `t`.

Comment: It looks like you think that the objects `p`, `l`, and `t` are connected in some way. They are three completely independent objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `l.LatimeaL(1,2,4);` on the object `l`.

The object `t` is created with `Triunghi t;`. It is not initialized by calling the `Latimeal` function. Therefore you are getting an undefined value.

You need to cal the `t.Latimeal(1,2,4)` function to initialize it, after creating the object.